# get file name include_once file based on name

Tags: php

I have multiple files in a directory for pages.

All the pages are the same except the content I enter based on
rental inspections.

bedroom1.php
bedroom2.php
bedroom3.php

But to get them to use the right header I need them to see the
correct header based on their own filename.

bedroom1.php to include header1.php

bedroom2.php to include header2.php

bedroom3.php to include header3.php

.......

bedroom10.php to include header10.php

I can get the filename easy enough.

I'm trying to use preg_match(Maybe should use something else?) 
but with not getting any errors in the logs so I'm not sure
what I'm missing and not knowing enough about file comparing
I'm lost.

EDIT: ADDED : Forgot to add, this code is in bedroom1.php etc...

Thanks in advance

```
<?php

$file = $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"];
$break = Explode('/', $file);
$pfile = $break[count($break) - 1];

if (preg_match('/bedroom . $i .php/', $pfile, $i)) {
    $number = $i[1];
    foreach(array('header') as $base) {
        include_once "$base$number.php";
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Explode should be lower case

Comment: What are you trying to do with `foreach(array('header') as $base)` ?

Comment: Trying to make sure it knows only to use the files with header in them since there are several other pages , page1.php, photo1.php, inspect1.php, marginal1.php etc.

Comment: I guess I could just remove that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
if (preg_match('/bedroom(\d+)\.php/', $pfile, $i)) {
```

You need to use `\d+` to match numeric digits, and put it inside parentheses to make it a capture group, so you can access it with `$i[1]`.

Comment: Still not reading the header file. Not making it in the preg_match. It simply has Bedroom 1 or depending on what bedroom file being viewed.

Comment: My fault. I had a missed spelled debroon in one spot. It's working. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$file  = basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], '.php');
$base  = 'header';
$parts = array();
if (preg_match('/bedroom(\d+)/', $file, $parts)) {
    include_once $base . $parts[1] . '.php';
} else {
    // the file doesn't follow the bedroom{number}.php structure
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
$file = $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"];
$baseName=basename($file);
$base="header";
preg_match_all('/\d+/', $baseName, $baseNameInt);
$basNameFile=$baseNameInt[0][0];

if(file_exists("$base$basNameFile.php")){
    include_once("$base$basNameFile.php");
} else {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])
```

you get the script name

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your array contains that necessitates the `foreach` (if that is just example code) but why not just:

```
$array  = array('header');
$suffix = str_replace($array, '', basename(__FILE__));

foreach($array as $base) {
    if(file_exist("$base$suffix")) {    
        include_once("$base$suffix");
    }
}
```

If the only thing that will be in the array is `header` then forgo the loop altogether.